# How to Validate Mongoose Schema With a Complex Object in Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a schema which has a complex object in an array:

```
foo:{
   bar:[{
       ItemA:String,
       ItemB:String
   }]
}
```

I want to add validation to the object in the array so as to check the array size (I want to limit the size of the array to 10).

How would I structure the schema so as to validate that sort of object in the array?

Comment: You would be better off doing this on the server with the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier on `$push`. That's a much better option than requiring the current document to be in memory in order to validate it's length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through [`validate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) option in Schema as below

```
var FooSchema = new Schema({
    foo:{
       bar: {
            type: [{
               ItemA:String,
               ItemB:String
            }],
            validate: [arrlimit, '{PATH} exceeds the limit 10']
        }
    }
});

function arrlimit(arr) {
    return arr && arr.length <= 10;
};
```

If you add more than `10` items into `bar` array like

```
var f = Foo({});
for (var i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    f.foo.bar.push({ItemA: 'A', ItemB: 'B'});

f.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save foo successfully....');
})
```

Error will come up

```
{ [ValidationError: Foo validation failed]
  message: 'Foo validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { 'foo.bar':
      { [ValidatorError: foo.bar exceeds the limit 10]
        properties: [Object],
        message: 'foo.bar exceeds the limit 10',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        kind: 'user defined',
        path: 'foo.bar',
        value: [Object] } } }
```